# Trouble with updating ngrx state

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I have an ngrx state like this:

```
company: {
  id: '1',
  name: 'myCompany',
  task: [{id: 1, name: 'task1', date: '20-01-2021', endDate: '22-01-2021'}, {id: 2, name: 'task2', date: '23-01-2021', endDate: '24-01-2021'}]
}
```

I have a function reducer that needs to update only some property of the task array.

the action object contains a property task that's an object that contains only the property I need to edit, and the id to match into the array. This is the function buy I got error because the object is read only.

```
 on(
CompanyAction.editTask,
(state, action): CompanyState => {
  const index = state.company.tasks.findIndex(el => el.id === action.taskId);

  // here I want to update the task that I've edited But I got error
  state.company.tasks[index] = { ...state.company.tasks[index], ...action.task };
  return {
    ...state,
    company: {
      ...state.company,
      tasks: state.company.tasks,
    },
  };
}),
```

Any suggestion?

P.S

I tried in this way, but if in the action I have only a single prop example name: string and I do this:

```
on(
  CompanyAction.editTask,
  (state, action): CompanyState => {
    const newTasks = state.company.tasks.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.taskId) {
        item.name = action.name  // this gives me a read only error
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    })
    return {
      ...state,
      company: {
        ...state.company,
        tasks: newTasks,
      },
    };
  }),
```

It gives me the same read only error.

Isn't correct to pass in the ngrx action a prop with only a single value to update a single property of the object?

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at ngrx-immer, which makes this  kind of operations simple. https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 on(
CompanyAction.editTask,
(state, action): CompanyState => {
  const index = state.company.tasks.findIndex(el => el.id === action.taskId);
  
  let companyTasks = {...state.company.tasks};
  let editingTask = companyTasks[index];
  companyTasks = companyTasks.filter((task, idx) => {return idx !== index});
  editingTask = {...editingTask, ...action.task};
  companyTasks.push(editingTask);
  
  return {
    ...state,
    company: {
      ...state.company,
      tasks: companyTasks,
    },
  };
}
```

First after finding index of desired task, Create a copy of all tasks named `companyTasks` .

then pick the task based on index (`editingTask`) and remove it from `companyTasks`. after editing it push it to `companyTasks`. and in returning state apply `companyTasks` to `tasks`.

Answer (score 0):

Could not test it but you can try this.

```js
on(
  CompanyAction.editTask,
  (state, action): CompanyState => {
    const newTasks = state.company.tasks.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.taskId) {
        // write code for what you wnat to do when id matches
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    })
    return {
      ...state,
      company: {
        ...state.company,
        tasks: newTasks,
      },
    };
  }
),
```

Comment: I tried but into the if if I try to edit a property in this way: item.name = action.name....it gives me an error. I don't want to create a shadow copy...